# How does one set up an Nginx server to use WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, nginx, websocket

I have a website that needs to work through an Nginx server.  At the moment, I don't believe the configuration for nginx is correct.  I currently have

```
server{
        server_name websitename.com;

       location /websocket/{
                proxy_pass http://websitename.com;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header $host;
        }

}
```

At the moment, I am receiving an error on the website that reads "SCRIPT12008: SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 200, OK", which I believe is because the protocol is not switching correctly.

Comment: `proxy_pass http://websitename.com;` that looks odd - proxy_pass usually "points" to whatever it is you are proxying for - in this case your proxy redirects to nginx itself - also, `proxy_header_header` - is there such a config item? see https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: The other important piece of information is ... what are you using as a websocket server? what port is it listening on?

Comment: By the way - you'll probably get better answers at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for this kind of question

Comment: Thanks for the points.  I mistyped for proxy_header_header (was supposed to be proxy_set_header).  I'm using port 22 for the websocket server.  I'll take a look at Server Fault.  Thanks!

Comment: port 22 is an unusual choice ... but it would be `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:22;`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the double quotes and the "Host" before $host to set the Host directive:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

So your config should would like this instead:

```
server{
        server_name websitename.com;

       location /websocket/{
                proxy_pass "http://websitename.com";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

}
```

Always check your syntax with 'nginx -t' command.